# Add login and connect to SQL with SQL Server Authentication

Tags: sql-server-2008, connection

I want to add a user in SQL Server 2008 so I can use SQL Server Authentication instead Windows Authentication for connecting to SQL, and have tried this code to create a user with login:

```
CREATE login [newLog] with password = 'passnewLognewLog'
```

I get it done, but when I want to connect to SQL Server using SQL Authentication, I get this message

> Cannot connect to "Mydb"
>   additional information: Login failed for user
>   'newLog'. (Microsoft SQL Server,
>   Error: 18456 )

What am I missing here?

Comment: Important, the mixed authentication has to be [enabled][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719399/sql-server-2008-cant-login-with-newly-created-user?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After creating the login, you need to add the user to the database.  This example is from the sql server [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173463.aspx) for `CREATE USER`:

```
CREATE LOGIN AbolrousHazem 
    WITH PASSWORD = '340$Uuxwp7Mcxo7Khy';
USE AdventureWorks2008R2;
CREATE USER AbolrousHazem FOR LOGIN AbolrousHazem;
GO
```

**Edit**

To test, I ran this T-SQL:

```
create login Foo with password ='f00';
go

use TestDB
create user Foo for Login Foo
go
```

and opened a connection successfully using this connection string:

```
"Server=<server>; user id=Foo; password=f00; initial catalog=TestDB"
```

Comment: I have tried that but can not login using SQL Server Authentication

Comment: what else do I have to do so I can connect using SQL Server Authentication with the created user??

Comment: @cMinor, see my edit.  I was able to create a login, add the user and connect successfully.  Is it possible you executed the `create user` statement in the context of a different database (perhaps master)?

Answer (score 5):

1. You need to create a user for the login, e.g.

   ```
   CREATE USER [newLog] FOR LOGIN [newLog] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
   ```
2. Check that mixed authentication is enabled: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1719476/188926

Answer (score 1):

Try the following. They worked for me when I had this connection issue.

```
 -When you are adding SQL user, make sure 'enforce password policy' is unchecked.
 -Make sure that user is mapped to the database with proper permissions.
 -on SSMS, right click server and then go to Security tab. Select 'SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode' option.
 -restart PC.
```