# Cannot login after creating the user in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

My problem is I cannot login into SQL Server after I've created a user. The user creation is successful, since the new user is listed under security/logins.

How to solve this issue ???

> Login failed for user 'sims'. The user is not associated with a
>   trusted SQL Server connection. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18452)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server 2008 can't login with newly created user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719399/sql-server-2008-cant-login-with-newly-created-user)

Answer (score 169, accepted):

Try setting your authentication mode to `mixed mode`. Your server does probably not accept logins using sql server accounts.

1. Open properties
2. Go to "Security"
3. Select "SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode"

Comment: Thankyou very much for your wonderful answer.It works correctly.I've no more doubt how to give permission to a user to access only particular database...

Comment: You pointed to actual error that is Mixed mode needs to be on and that saved my hours... Thank you...

Comment: Here is a step by step guide:
https://help.blacknight.com/hc/en-us/articles/212511129-Set-MS-SQL-to-mixed-mode-Authentication-on-Windows-Cloud-VM

Comment: This requires the service to be restarted after committing the changes.

Comment: Yep, go into the services app and restart the sql server service

Answer (score 191):

SQL Server was not configured to allow mixed authentication. Here are steps to fix:

1. Right-click on SQL Server instance at root of Object Explorer,
2. click on Properties.
3. Select Security from the left pane.
4. Select the SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode radio button, and
5. click OK.
6. Open up Services and restart the SQL Service (SQLEXPRESS) Windows service.

Comment: +1 for restarting the services. the only bit was missing before it worked... you saved from suicide... !

Comment: What's "Object Explorer"?

Comment: @Maxim in the Management Studio - it's the left column (pane)

Comment: That's the right answer, you need to restart the service (not the job)

Comment: Yep, just closing and re-opening SSMS does NOT fix the issue. This should be accepted answer IMO as well

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I'm not the only one who almost gave up and took a bullet before going stackoverflow.

Comment: To me also helped to set the user Default database to master: Object Explorer > Security > Logins > [user] > Properties > General > Default database ---> master

Comment: When you switch authentication modes supported you get a message box telling you to restart the sql express windows service, so it should be intuitive what to do next.

Answer (score 39):

basically :
Right click Server for properties...

[image]properties

for detailed explanation:
If you're encountering the "Login failed for user" error when trying to log in to SQL Server after creating a new user, you can follow these steps to resolve the issue:

Change Authentication Mode:

Right-click on the SQL Server instance and select "Properties."
In the Properties window, navigate to the "Security" section.
Choose the "SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode" option.
Click "OK" to save the changes.

Restart SQL Service:

- Open the SQL Server Configuration Manager.
- Locate the SQL Server service (e.g., SQLEXPRESS) and restart it.

Additional Troubleshooting Steps:

- If the issue persists, make sure the user is associated with the correct database and has appropriate permissions.
- Double-check the connection string in your application to ensure it specifies the correct authentication mode and user credentials.

**Remember to back up your SQL Server settings before making any changes.**