# Can't login in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to create a login in SQL Server Management Studio. I was successful in the creation, but after that I can't login in it. I will leave the steps below

Fixed the problem. [Solution](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GDoOg_oeKEI)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it that you're setting up the user in server LAPTOP-xxxxxxx whereas the final login attempt is to Localhost?

Comment: So how can I set up the user in localhost?

Comment: To that I leave it to others... I don't do much of that. I'm not even sure what I asked is the issue. Can you actually log on to LAPTOP-xxxxx with your test user?

Comment: Sql Server makes a distinction between **logins** and **users**. Is the login mapped as **user** for any databases?

Comment: Did you check the SQL Server errorlog for what _state_ is being returned with the 18456 error? It will have additional context and the state you can [cross-reference here](https://sqlblog.org/2020/07/28/troubleshooting-error-18456).

Comment: If `LAPTOP-xxxxxxx` is not the same machine as the one where SSMS is running, then you need to decide where you want to run SQL Server and which instance you actually want `test` to connect to. If they are different and you want `test` to connect to the SQL Server running on `localhost`, then you need to create the login on `localhost` too, not just on `LAPTOP-xxxxxxx`. If you want to connect to the instance running on `LAPTOP-xxxxxxx`, then you shouldn't have `localhost` in your last step; connect to the same machine where you created the login. Why use different names in these steps?

Comment: I tried using LAPTOP-xxxxx to login with test and ir didn't work either

Comment: Does the server actually have SQL Server authentication enabled? In your third screen shot it appears all non-Windows logins are disabled. Possibly during installation you chose "Windows Authentication mode" instead of "SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot login after creating the user in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11625899/cannot-login-after-creating-the-user-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your server `Properties --> Security --> Server authentication`

If `SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode` selected you will be fine.

If not, Follow steps below:

> - Right-click on your server
> - Go to option Security
> - Check the option "SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode"
> - Click on Ok button
> - Restart SQL Express Service ("Windows Key" on keyboard and write "Services", and then Enter key)
> - After SQL services restarted, you should be able to login with user and password

Answer (score 0):

These are the steps to take to create a login:

1. Click right on database ,choose security , choose SQL with Windows authentication and Both failed....
2. Restart SQL Server service
3. Create database
4. Create login and a sign the name of database to the user from choosing "Default Database"
5. Be sure you a sign to user mapping database
6. Server name :

   - if local choose the name of computer name that you choose from first if you do not know choose from drop list of server name  to see what available name
   - if you have a ip static put the server name like that `:000.00.00.00\\SQLSERVER2019,1433`, name and password.