# Logins created in SQL Server Management Studio are not able to log in

Tags: sql-server, authentication

I've been working to try and connect an ASP.NET application to an IIS Site running in an App Pool using Integrated Security.  I was eventually unsuccessful in that attempt until I made the Login I'd created to represent the App Pool a Sysadmin, which I understand is not a good thing to leave in there.  It's on localhost, but it still makes me uneasy.

So I decided to try to use a Login/Password combo instead of Integrated Security.  To that end, I created a new Login in my SQL Server Management Studio:
[image: My newly created Login]

And told it to use a password, making sure that I know what the password and username are.

- My Default database is master
- Server Roles is only 'public'
- In User Mapping I added db_owner to one of my databases, and all the others are only 'public'
- In Securables, 'Connect SQL' is Granted to the SQLEXPRESS server

I then disconnected from SSMS and tried to reconnect using my newly-created Login.

[image: Logging in with my new Login]

It didn't allow me to log in:

[image: Nope, denied.]

According to:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/create-a-login

`After creating a login, the login can connect to SQL Server, but does not necessarily have sufficient permission to perform any useful work.`

However, that appears to not be the case in this instance.  What am I doing wrong?

I did make sure that my Server Authentication was set correctly, per [SQL Server 2008 can't login with newly created user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719399/sql-server-2008-cant-login-with-newly-created-user)

Another data point: when I try (and fail) to log in 10 times in rapid succession and then go back in with Windows authentication, the 'Login is locked out' notification in the Status tab is *not* checked.

Comment: Check SQL Server **error log** to find out the reason of failure. The next row to 18456 error says in clear what it was caused by

Comment: Good point!  It says that 'Server is configured for Windows authentication only. [CLIENT: <local machine>]', but when I look at the Server properties -> security, the 'SQL Server and Windows Authentication Mode' radio button is selected.  I even restarted SSMS after changing it to that, but no luck.  Any idea why the server is apparently ignoring that setting?

Comment: GOT IT!  I needed to restart the SQLEXPRESS Service in Windows, rather than just restarting SSMS.  Thanks or your help!

Answer (score 1):

The thing I was missing was going to Windows Services, and restarting SQLEXPRESS to get the change to 'SQL Server and Windows Authentication Mode' to take effect.

After I did that, I was able to log in with my testuser.