# Can't connect to local database with user and pass credentials

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to connect to a local SQL Server database but it gives me this error:

> Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\Username'.

When I open SQL server and look in the `Security\Logins` folder then I do see the user `DOMAIN\Username`. This is also the user that I use to login into Windows with.

My connection string looks like this:

```
<add name="ServerConfiguration"
       connectionString="server=localhost; database=BN_Configuration; 
       Integrated Security=false; User ID=DOMAIN\Username; Password=123456;" 
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Anyone any idea why I can't login with these credentials?

--

**Note** I wish to authenticate with a user that exists in the SQL Server database. So I do  NOT want to do Windows authentication with `Integrated Security` set to `false`.

Comment: Try looking in Windows' Event Log in the Security section on the Database server for a more detailed error message.

Comment: You cannot use domain users this way. Either create a SQL Server user or `Integrated Security=true, remove `User ID` and `Password` and it will use the user running the process.

Comment: @DavidG I just created a new user in SQL Server. But when I try to login with the new credentials then it still says that I can't login.

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750303, then clarify your question

Comment: Your edit shows you still don't quite get how SQL security works. When you created the SQL user, did you create it from the domain or did you give it a new username/password?

Comment: @DavidG I gave it a new username/password. It's a SQL Server account.

Comment: @Vivendi Then try my answer, it may help.

Comment: Try `User ID=Username; Password=123456;`

Comment: @Jesuraja That's what I have for the new SQL user, but it's not working either: `connectionString="server=localhost; database=BN_Configuration; 
       Integrated Security=false; User ID=ConfigUser; Password=SecretPass1;"`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using a Windows credential as SQL Server credential. Try integrated security = true, and not to specify user ID and password.

Comment: Tried that but then it still says that I can't login: Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\BBL004$'. And BBL004 is my computer name.

Comment: @Vivendi Then change your application to run as a different account.

Answer (score 0):

In your connection string `Integrated Security=false` is saying user ID and password are specified in the connection for an account that exists in SQL Server but is NOT a domain user. When `Integrated Security=true`, the current Windows account credentials are used for authentication. If it's an application it will use the user who is currently logged in, and for a web application it all depends on how your application pool is set up.

You are mixing up the definitions by saying ``Integrated Security=false` but passing domain credentials which is not possible.

**Using a domain account**

1. Set `Integrated Security=true`
2. Remove the `user id` and `password` sections.
3. Map the domain account in SQL Server making sure to set `Windows authentication`
4. If it's a web application, make sure your application pool is set to run under that domain account.

**Using a SQL Server Account**

1. Set `Integrated Security=false`
2. Create a SQL login, making sure it uses `SQL Server authentication`
3. Set the `User ID` and `Password` properties of your connection string to be the same details you created above.

**Note:** Final point, make sure the user also has access to the database you are connecting to (in your case `BN_Configuration`).